# Retaining money from client until the product comes

Tags: paypal, currency, retain, confirmation

I know this question is not especifically technical, but I can't find in any other place. I am developing a marketplace in woocommerce, but I want to retain the money of a client until the product arrives, or the service is completed, and after the client confirms, the money will be sent for the seller. I want to make that automatically, using Paypal. I simply don't know where to start. In summary, the client's money should come into my account, then after the client's confirmation the money (minus the fee) should be sent automatically for the client. If necessary, I can change the platform of the marketplace for another kind.

Answer (score 0):

A way to send money from your account to others with PayPal is to use Payouts: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts .

---

There is also a feature designed for marketplaces: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/delayed-disbursement/ , however in order to use that for live payments you must be an approved PayPal partner as noted in the box here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/get-started/#get-api-credentials